# How can I set bootstrap-vue theme colors to css variables?

Tags: css, vue.js, sass, bootstrap-vue

I'm using bootstrap-vue and would like to be able to override the theme colors dynamically at runtime (after compiling the scss).  To do this I'm following this guide: https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/reference/theming to set the bootstrap theme colors to a css variable:

```
$theme-colors: (
  "info": var(--info)
);

@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

However, when I compile the scss I get the following error:

```
SassError: argument `$color-2` of `mix($color-1, $color-2, $weight: 50%)` must be a color
on line 106 of node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_functions.scss, in function `mix`
```

Is it possible to inject css variables like I want?  If so how?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like I've run into a known limitation to bootstrap's scss.  This blog outlines a workaround by overriding bootstraps functions:
[Changing Bootstrap Theme at Runtime with CSS Variables](https://blog.wick.technology/runtime-dynamic-bootstrap-theme/)

However it reportedly doesn't work with IE 11.